# Ajax call to web service returns Error 401: Unauthorized

Tags: c#, web-services, iis, .aspxauth

Hello I have a C# ASMX Web Service, everything works fine on my local IIS, the problem is when I move my project to my server. Now when I try to execute any ajax call I get a form to type username and password. All username and password are wrong (I don't know which credentials is looking for) if I close the form I get the Error 401: Unauthorized message. Something weird is that if I enter to my webservice by writing the url on another window I can see all my web methods and if I return to my website and refresh the page now the system don't ask for any username or password and everything works fine.

On server IIS I change Authentication to Anonymus Authentication but this doesn't solve my problem.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Create a test HTML page there and try to see what happens when you access the HTML page. That in turn can tell what's up.

Comment: According to your description, it seems that you have enabled the windows auth in your application that caused your ajax request need auth firstly. The reason why your browser doesn't show the auth form is the browser will send the credenticial to the server. I suggest you could check if there is some special auth setting in your codes or IIS web.config again.